# Vuetify. v-img component doesn't display

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is a piece of code that doesn't work. the picture is not displayed. I checked the path to the picture everything is ok. I don't understand what the problem is. Everything is clear in the console.

```
<v-card v-for="(course, i) in courses" :key="i">
  <v-img :src="course.src"></v-img>
    <v-card-subtitle>{{ course.title }}</v-card-subtitle>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-progress-linear
        v-model="art"
        color="blue-grey"
        height="25"
        >
        <template v-slot="{ value }">
          <strong>{{ Math.ceil(value) }}%</strong>
        </template>
      </v-progress-linear>
    <span>
      <v-btn type="success">
        Davom ettirish
      </v-btn>
     </span>
   </v-card-actions>
</v-card>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      courses: [
        {title: 'Rassomchilik', src: '../assets/images/course-maths.png'},
        {title: 'Matematikadan oliy ta`lim muassasalari uchun tayyorgarlik kursi', src: '../assets/images/course-maths.png'}
      ],
      art: 43,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you must use require like this:

```
require('@/assets/images/course-maths.png')
```

Comment: Please tell user which line in code to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      courses: [
        {title: 'Rassomchilik', src: require('../assets/images/course-maths.png')},
        {title: 'Matematikadan oliy ta`lim muassasalari uchun tayyorgarlik kursi', src: require('../assets/images/course-maths.png')}
      ],
      art: 43,
    }),
  }
</script>
```

See [this part](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) of VueCLI documentation for more details how static assets are handled by Vue CLI/Webpack. This works automatically when you reference it directly (`<img src='../assets/img.png'`) because Webpack is configured to look for specific tags/attributes (like `img`/`src`). But you have file paths as a data in JS, so you must use `require` function directly - it will be transformed by Webpack during build into correct URL/path....

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood)